# How do resistances change on Legendary difficulty in Titan Quest?

Tags: titan-quest

I just want to be prepared for when I hit legendary difficulty on titan quest. By how much percentage will my primary and secondary resistances drop in legendary difficulty?

Comment: Wow an upvote w/o an answer so far O.o

Comment: What's so strange about that?

Comment: ack. never mind. I'm being naive :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primary resistances get -40% in Epic and -100% in Legendary.

Up until patch 1.15, secondary resistances were also penalized, by -25% in Epic and -50% in legendary. Since patch 1.15 secondary resistances are no longer penalized at all.

[source1](http://www.titanquest.net/tq-forum/threads/18328-Simple-question-on-resistances)
[source2](http://www.strategyinformer.com/pc/titanquest/patch/9248.html?details=1)
[source3](http://www.titanquest.net/tq-forum/threads/27255-About-secondary-resistances)
[source4](http://www.titanquest.net/tq-forum/threads/27179-NEGATIVE-Resistances)

Comment: I'm on 1.08 , so I can expect a bumpy road ahead

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Anniversary edition has secondary resist lowered again in higher difficulties